# How can I perform update operation on nested serializer data in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hii I am new to django rest framework,I want to perform update operation on nested serialized data but unable to complete it.Someone please look into it and suggest me the update method code.Thank you..

```
    My Models are:
    
    class MyUser(AbstractUser):
        bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
        is_younger = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        friends = models.ManyToManyField('self',blank=True, related_name="friends")
    
    
    
    class Profile(models.Model):
        genders = [
            ("M", "Male"),
            ("F", "Female"),
        ]
    
        user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=genders)
        contact = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact phone number')
        address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile/", db_index=True, default="profile/default.jpg")
        
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
    
    
    ----Serializers are:
    
    class UsersProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = '__all__'
    
    
    class ListUsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        profile = UsersProfileSerializer(
            read_only=True, many=True, source='profile_set')
    
        class Meta:
            model = MyUser
            fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'is_younger',
                      'friends', 'profile']
    
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            profiles_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
            profiles = (instance.profile).all()
            profiles = list(profiles)
            instance.bio = validated_data.get('bio', instance.bio)
            instance.save()
    
            for profile_data in profiles_data:
                profile = profiles.pop(0)
                profile.contact = profile_data.get('contact', profile.contact)
                profile.address = profile_data.get('address', profile.address)
                profile.save()
            return instance


Below is View code:

class CheckUserDetailsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()


    def list(self, request):
        serializer = ListUsersSerializer(self.queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request,pk=None):
        user = generics.get_object_or_404(self.queryset,pk=pk)
        serializer = ListUsersSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I know ,I should create a update method in my viewset code but I found some related code and use them by doing some changes according to my need but those are not working.If there is problem in my serializer's update method, then please point my mistake or it can be done by writing update method in views then please give me some hint or provide me some code .Thank you

Comment: You will write an update method for nested serializer.

Comment: I have written an update method for nested serializer.You mean I should create an update method in view.

Comment: Are you trying to update the MyUser instance in this case through the profile endpoint? In that case, you could just create a profiles endpoint as you would and pop the MyUser data in the update method and run the user update manually.

Comment: kwanj..!, I want to update both MyUser and Profile instance .Should I create an update method in ListUsersSerializer or it is okay in views.Can you please suggest me some update code so that I can know where I am doing mistake.Thanks

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: kwanj Can you please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/q/69560033/17143140

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there are many ways to go about it and here is one. Have a view that toggles between two serializers depending on the request and override the update method in the update serializer. This way you will update the user through the profile endpoint using a user_data key.

Have  PATCH/PUT serializers

```
class UsersProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = '__all__'


class UsersProfileUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_data = serializers.DictField()

    class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = '__all__'

   def update(self, instance, validated_data):
     user_data = validated_data.pop('user_data', None)
     for (key, value) in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance, key, value)
     if user_data is not None:
       user_instance = instance.user
       for (key, value) in user_data.items():
           setattr(user_instance, key, value)
       user_instance.save()
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

View:

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   """
     API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
   """
   queryset = Profile.objects.all()

   def get_serializer_class(self):
     if self.action == 'update':
        return UsersProfileUpdateSerializer
     return UsersProfileSerializer
```

Example of update object:

```
{
  "age":18,
  "user_data": {
    "bio": "update"
  }
}
```